# Unable to list all products in jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to list all the products in a jade file called productlist .jade file . But it is not displaying anything.

**Jade file :**

```
extends mylayout

doctype html
html(lang= 'en')
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge,chrome=1')
    title List of all products

block content
  h1 Product list
   p  Below you will see list of all products
   br
   each myuser in products
    p #{myuser.prodName}
```

**USers.js file(controller file)**

```
myRouter.get('/products',function(req,res){

    prodModel.find(function(err,result){

      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      }

      else {

         res.send(result);
      }
    }); // end prod model find
 }); // end get products find


  });// end prod model find 

}); // // end route to get a particular product
```

Above is the route I have written to display all the products.

Can anybody tell what changes I have to make ?

Comment: Maybe try reformatting your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not rendering the view correctly nor are you sending the results to the view. Your controller should look something like the following (assuming mongoose):

```
myRouter.get('/products', async (req,res) => {
  const products = await prodModel.find()
  res.render('products', { products })
})
```

Then in the view you'd do something like:

```
ul
  each product in products
    li= product
```

This answer assumes:

- A view named `products.{pug,jade}` in the root of the `views/` directory.
- You've configured your `views/` correctly.

Comment: var products = prodModel.find(function(err,product){
       if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      }

      else {
         
         res.send('products',{ products })
      }

Comment: Please specify what changes needs to be done in jade file as it is showing cannot get/users/products.

Comment: Added small example.

Comment: Please make changes to the code and explain if possible